# .htaccess clean URL and relative paths

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following in my .htaccess which is :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?type=cat&id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)$ /index.php?type=page&name=$1
```

This seems to work just fine but relative paths to pictures and css files inside of index.php become broken in the second case (Page). did not work. In second case, all images are pointing to page/images/ instead of image/

Other than hardcoding the actual path to images, is there any other way to fix this?

images, css, js folders are located in the root. This is how the root looks like

```
.htaccess
index.php
images/
css/
js/
```

Comment: what are the folders for images,js,css etc...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RewriteCond directives only apply to the rule directly following them.Try the follwing

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?type=cat&id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)$ /index.php?type=page&name=$1 [L]

#rewrite requests for page/images to images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page(/images/.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . %1 [L]
```

EDIT.
Modified to rewrite page/images to images

Comment: did not work. In second case, all images are pointing to page/images/ instead of image/

Comment: edited so second rule does not apply to css etc. You can add other resources as necessary

Comment: How about changing this line RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page(/images/.+)$ [NC] to re-write pages/js and pages/css

Comment: if those are both folders, try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page(/images/(js|css)/.+)$ [NC]`