# PHP - Map assets directory from public to root

Tags: php

I inherited a PHP framework that's constructed with the app itself living in the app directory and all the public facing content in the public directory.

```
- app
- public
   - assets
   - views
```

So to reference the scripts and stylesheets, it's written out as `http://site.dev/public/assets/asset.file` as that's where it lives.

It was requested that the assets be referenced as `/assets/asset.file` rather than the full path, but the assets still have to remain in the public directory. It seems pointless and arbitrary, but I have to try to at least do what was requested.

The [Craft CMS](https://buildwithcraft.com/) is structured in a similar way with the assets living in the public directory, but are written out in the template the way I'm needing.

So just wondering if there is some type of function or method that can route/map a directory to be written out in this manner? Or just exclude the public directory in the path?

Thanks in an advance for any assistance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using apache, check out the `.htaccess` file. More info can be found [here](https://www.branded3.com/blog/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/assets/(.*)$ /public/assets/$1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use htaccess to rewrite the URLs. You could have site.com/css/style.css where the /css folder doesn't exist, and the htaccess actually maps it to public/assets/css or however you need it.

This has been covered many times, you just need to modify code you find to fit your needs..

Here is an example of a similar SO question that is answered: [.htaccess clean URL and relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482817/htaccess-clean-url-and-relative-paths)

Answer (score 0):

The public and the app directories are separated for a very good reason:

The app directory is your private application space which should NOT be visible to the outside.

So generally speaking: The author of your application was most likely well aware of that problem (that's why he structured it that way) and your problem might solve itself if you point your webservers document root to the public directory. Most likely the path will fix itself then (assuming that the author was REALLY aware of that ;) ).

There is most likely an index.php or app.php in the public directory which might need an additional RewriteRule. However that is very application/framework specific. Maybe you find a README.